# Ansible win_shell executes Powershell cmdlet using old powershell.exe version 4.0 instead of 5.0

Tags: powershell, ansible

I want to run cmdlet *Get-LocalGroupMember* using an Ansible playbook.

1) Running *Get-LocalGroupMember* in the server.
The execution was successful.
A check on the Powershell version showed version 5.1.14409.1005.

2) Running *Get-LocalGroupMember* using the Ansible playbook.
The execution was not successful.
A check on the playbook log found the followings.

- It cannot find the cmdlet *Get-LocalGroupMember*.
- It reported that the Powershell version used is version 4.0.

The server was rebooted. Then, the playbook is execution again. It still gave the same error result.

What could be the reason that win_shell still wants to use old powershell.exe v4.0 ? 
Thank you.

This is the playbook.

```
---
- name: add domain user to Windows
  hosts: '{{ host }}'
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    user: null
  tasks:
  - name: add user
    win_shell:
      "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
#      - '$adminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:computername/Administrators"'
#      -  '$adminGroup.add("WinNT://astro.com.my/{{ user }}")'
      - $PSversiontable
      - Get-LocalGroupMember Administrators
```

This is the powershell version of the host. Note the version is 5.0.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $PSversiontable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1005
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1005
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

This is the result of a cmdlet.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-LocalGroupMember Administrators

ObjectClass Name                       PrincipalSource
----------- ----                       ---------------
User        A.COM\AKJASHIS
```

This is the result running the cmdlet using the playbook.
Note the value of PSVersion  is 4.0 not 5.0.

```
[root@hpcprdrhe01 playbook]# ansible-playbook -v win-add-domain-user.yml -e "host=ipcrec101" -e "user=aflahmad"
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

PLAY [add domain user to Windows] ***************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [add user] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [ipcrec101] => (item=$PSversiontable) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "cmd": "$PSversiontable", "delta": "0:00:01.281267", "end": "2020-05-03 06:35:29.311512", "item": "$PSversiontable", "rc": 0, "start": "2020-05-03 06:35:28.030245", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "\r\nName                           Value                                           \r\n----                           -----                                           \r\nPSVersion                      4.0                                             \r\nWSManStackVersion              3.0                                             \r\nSerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                         \r\nCLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                 \r\nBuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17400                                  \r\nPSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}                            \r\nPSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2                                             \r\n\r\n\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["", "Name                           Value                                           ", "----                           -----                                           ", "PSVersion                      4.0                                             ", "WSManStackVersion              3.0                                             ", "SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                         ", "CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                 ", "BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17400                                  ", "PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}                            ", "PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2                                             ", "", ""]}
failed: [ipcrec101] (item=Get-LocalGroupMember Administrators) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "cmd": "Get-LocalGroupMember Administrators", "delta": "0:00:01.484411", "end": "2020-05-03 06:35:34.749100", "item": "Get-LocalGroupMember Administrators", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2020-05-03 06:35:33.264689", "stderr": "Get-LocalGroupMember : The term 'Get-LocalGroupMember' is not recognized as \r\nthe name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the \r\nspelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is \r\ncorrect and try again.\r\nAt line:1 char:65\r\n+ [Console]::InputEncoding = New-Object Text.UTF8Encoding $false; \r\nGet-LocalGroupMe ...\r\n+                                                                 \r\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-LocalGroupMember:String) [] \r\n   , CommandNotFoundException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException", "stderr_lines": ["Get-LocalGroupMember : The term 'Get-LocalGroupMember' is not recognized as ", "the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the ", "spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is ", "correct and try again.", "At line:1 char:65", "+ [Console]::InputEncoding = New-Object Text.UTF8Encoding $false; ", "Get-LocalGroupMe ...", "+                                                                 ", "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", "    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-LocalGroupMember:String) [] ", "   , CommandNotFoundException", "    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************
ipc101               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I don't know Ansible, but the first question that comes to mind is: Does the playbook run on the same computer?

Comment: In fact, `BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17400` in your output implies that it is running on a different machine.

Comment: If the problem was simply not realizing that it is the _target machine's_ PowerShell version that matters, please consider deleting your question, as it is unlikely to be of interest to future readers. Otherwise, please update your question to clarify the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing...

In */etc/ansible/hosts*, the target server, *ipcrec101*, points to another target server that is using Powershell version 4.0.

```
[root@hpcprdrhe01 playbook]# ansible-playbook -v win-add-domain-user.yml -e "host=ipcrec101"
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

PLAY [add domain user to Windows] ***************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [add user using win_shell] *****************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [ipcrec101] => (item=$PSversiontable) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "cmd": "$PSversiontable", "delta": "0:00:00.628005", "end"
: "2020-05-07 03:15:46.635697", "item": "$PSversiontable", "rc": 0, "start": "2020-05-07 03:15:46.007691", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "\r\nName                           Value                                           \r\n----                           -----                                           \r\nPSVersion                      5.1.14409.1005                                  \r\nPSEdition                      Desktop                                         \r\nPSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                         \r\nBuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1005                                 \r\nCLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                 \r\nWSManStackVersion              3.0                                             \r\nPSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                             \r\nSerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                         \r\n\r\n\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["", "Name                           Value                                           $, "----                           -----                                           ", "PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1005                                  ", "PSEdition                      Desktop                                         ", "PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                         ", "BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1005                                 ", "CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                 ", "WSManStackVersion              3.0                                             ", "PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                             ", "SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                         ", "", ""]}

TASK [add user using win_command] **************************************************************************************************************************$
changed: [ipcrec101] => (item=powershell.exe $PSversiontable) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "cmd": "powershell.exe $PSversiontable", "$elta": "0:00:00.384017", "end": "2020-05-07 03:15:49.520862", "item": "powershell.exe $PSversiontable", "rc": 0, "start": "2020-05-07 03:15:49.136845", "std$rr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "\r\nName                           Value                                           \r\n----                           -----                                           \r\nPSVersion                      5.1.14409.1005                                  \r\nPSEdition                      Desktop                                         \r\nPSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                         \r\nBuildVersio$                   10.0.14409.1005                                 \r\nCLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                 \r\nWS$anStackVersion              3.0                                             \r\nPSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                             \r\nSerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                         \r\n\r\n\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["", "Name                           Val$e                                           ", "----                           -----                                           ", "PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1005                                  ", "PSEdition                      Desktop                                         ", "PSCompatibleVersi
ons           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                         ", "BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1005                                 ", "CLRVersi
on                     4.0.30319.42000                                 ", "WSManStackVersion              3.0                                             ",
"PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                             ", "SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
      ", "", ""]}
changed: [ipcrec101] => (item=c:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe $PSversiontable) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true,
"cmd": "c:\\windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe $PSversiontable", "delta": "0:00:00.395995", "end": "2020-05-07 03:15:52.134291", "ite
m": "c:\\windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe $PSversiontable", "rc": 0, "start": "2020-05-07 03:15:51.738295", "stderr": "", "stderr_l
ines": [], "stdout": "\r\nName                           Value                                           \r\n----                           -----
                               \r\nPSVersion                      5.1.14409.1005                                  \r\nPSEdition                      Desktop
                                        \r\nPSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                         \r\nBuildVersion
 10.0.14409.1005                                 \r\nCLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                 \r\nWSManStackVersion
          3.0                                             \r\nPSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                             \r\nSerializatio
nVersion           1.1.0.1                                         \r\n\r\n\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["", "Name                           Value
                          ", "----                           -----                                           ", "PSVersion                      5.1.14409.100
5                                  ", "PSEdition                      Desktop                                         ", "PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0
, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                         ", "BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1005                                 ", "CLRVersion
     4.0.30319.42000                                 ", "WSManStackVersion              3.0                                             ", "PSRemotingProtoco
lVersion      2.3                                             ", "SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                         ", "", ""]}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************
ipcrec101               : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```